# List of Classes in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, activerecord, mongoid

I need to list all Class (with attributes if possible) present in my model folder and I succeed to do it through ActiveRecord but I can't find any solutions cross-ORM and cross-DB.

---

An example is a lot easier to understand than my words:

**Files Structure**

```
 app
. models
.. user.rb
.. post.rb
.. comment.rb
```

**Inside Files**

```
class User
  ...
end

class Post
  ...
end

class Comment
  ...
end
```

**Expected**

```
[User,Post,Comment]
```

**Existing but uncomplete solution**

For now, I'm listing the classes thanks to than small piece of Code

```
model_name = []
ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.each do |t|
  model_name << t.name.camelize
end
model_name
```

**Question**

I'm looking for to the same type of method but without ActiveRecord.
I need to access the list of classes (with attributes if possible) no matter the ORM or the type of the DB.
I thought about parsing models' folder but it does not seems to be a good solution to me.

Have you an idea about some solutions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few angles of attack I can think of:

1. Most ORMs have a similar pattern as ActiveRecord, which means that model classes need to inherit from (or include) some base class, which you can then introspect for decendants (for example `Sequel::Model.decendants` for [sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/)
2. If all of your models are declared under a known `Module` (namespace), you can list the classes declared under a specific module using the [`constants`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Module.html#method-i-constants) method

   ```
   MyModels.constants
   # => [MyModels::User,MyModels::Post,MyModels::Comment]
   ```
3. If you have control on the timing of the *loading* of the classes (i.e. they are not autoloaded), you can enumerate the classes in the object space before and after loading your models, something like this:

   ```
   classes_before = Set.new
   ObjectSpace.each_object do |cl| 
     classes_before << cl if cl.class == Class
   end
   Dir.glob('app/models/*.rb').each do |model|
     require model
   end
   classes_after = Set.new
   ObjectSpace.each_object do |cl| 
     classes_after << cl if cl.class == Class
   end
   model_classes = classes_after - classes_before
   ```
4. If you know the all the model classes are written by rails idioms (single class in each file, with the name of the file as a snake_case of the name of the class), you can also simply collect the names of the files under the `models` folder:

   ```
   Dir.glob('app/models/*.rb').map do |file|
     file[/app\/models\/(.*)\.rb/, 1].camelize
   end
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you convinced me that there's no magical solution after all, only different types of fixes that can bring me the expected result.
I forgot to mention it was for using it in a gem, so it will be tricky but thanks to the different solutions you give me, I'll find the best one among these ones.